# Combine multiple rows based on ID column

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following df:

```
df<- structure(list(X18.digit.contact.id = c("0034y00002kIZ3rAAG", 
"0034y00002kIZ3rAAG", "0034y00002kIZ3rAAG", "0034y00002PpX11AAF", 
"0034y00002PpX11AAF", "0034y00002PpX11AAF", "0034y00002jHjYKAA0", 
"0034y00002jHjYKAA0", "0034y00002jHjYKAA0"), `Fitness Goal` = c(2L, 
NA, NA, -1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), `Nutrition/Hydration Goal` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 2L, NA, NA), `Lifestyle Goal` = c(NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
    X18.digit.contact.id = c("0034y00002PpX11AAF", "0034y00002jHjYKAA0", 
    "0034y00002kIZ3rAAG"), .rows = structure(list(4:6, 7:9, 1:3), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I'm hoping to collapse these rows together based on the X18contactid column. So, the final df would consist of 3 rows (3 unique IDs), and four columns (id, fitness goal, nutrition/hydration, lifestyle).

I've tried various solutions that I've found on here from summarize functions to

```
 lapply: df2<- df[, lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse=""), by=X18.digit.contact.id]
```

However, none of them seem to work. I can pivot it longer, remove the NA's and then pivot it wide again which gives me the row format that I want, however, it gives the following warning message which restricts the functions I am able to do on the columns afterwards:

```
Values from `value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
```

Note: I can get rid of this warning message by assigning a unique row number to each when I use `pivot_wider`, however, the output is the same as `df`, where the rows are not grouped by the id variable.

Any help/insight with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Base R:

```
aggregate(.~X18.digit.contact.id, df, na.omit, na.action = identity)

  X18.digit.contact.id Fitness Goal Nutrition/Hydration Goal Lifestyle Goal
1   0034y00002jHjYKAA0            1                        2              1
2   0034y00002kIZ3rAAG            2                        1              2
3   0034y00002PpX11AAF           -1                        0              0
```

---

```
pivot_longer(df,-1, values_drop_na = TRUE)%>%
   pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   X18.digit.contact.id [3]
  X18.digit.contact.id `Fitness Goal` `Nutrition/Hydration Goal` `Lifestyle Goal`
  <chr>                         <int>                      <int>            <int>
1 0034y00002kIZ3rAAG                2                          1                2
2 0034y00002PpX11AAF               -1                          0                0
3 0034y00002jHjYKAA0                1                          2                1
```

---

In datatable

```
dcast(na.omit(melt(df, 1)),X18.digit.contact.id~variable)
   X18.digit.contact.id Fitness Goal Nutrition/Hydration Goal Lifestyle Goal
1:   0034y00002PpX11AAF           -1                        0              0
2:   0034y00002jHjYKAA0            1                        2              1
3:   0034y00002kIZ3rAAG            2                        1              2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `data.table`, you can try

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), X18.digit.contact.id]
   X18.digit.contact.id Fitness Goal Nutrition/Hydration Goal Lifestyle Goal
1:   0034y00002kIZ3rAAG            2                        1              2
2:   0034y00002PpX11AAF           -1                        0              0
3:   0034y00002jHjYKAA0            1                        2              1
```

---

Since the data you shared is already **grouped**, you can simply run

```
df %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), na.omit))
```

which gives

```
  X18.digit.contact.id `Fitness Goal` Nutrition/Hydration Goa…¹ `Lifestyle Goal`
  <chr>                         <int>                     <int>            <int>
1 0034y00002PpX11AAF               -1                         0                0
2 0034y00002jHjYKAA0                1                         2                1
3 0034y00002kIZ3rAAG                2                         1                2
```